# Integrar Mercado Pago a react-native

Tags: mercadopago, react-native

Mi consulta es la siguiente tengo que desarrollar un proyecto con mercado pago e integrarlo a una aplicación en react-native, la aplicación ya está desarrollada, ¿es posible integrar mercado pago a react-native?.

Comment: Hola Jose, bienvenido. Te sugiero completar el [tour] del sitio. **Para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad te recomiendo leer [ask]**

Comment: en un grupo de facebook especificamente en React Native en Español un desarrollador creo una libreria de pago para solucionar este problema, te adjunto link al post:
[Post de facebook del desarrollador](https://www.facebook.com/groups/476674372721669/permalink/983127162076385/)

Comment: Si aún te interesa, aquí puedes revisar el tema que hice: https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-mercado-pago-enterprise

Answer (score 1):

Ahora si es posible gracias a esta libreria [`react-native-mercadopago-checkout`](https://github.com/javi10823/react-native-mercadopago-checkout)

Los pasos son simples:

**Instalacion:**

> YARN
>
> yarn add react-native-mercadopago-checkout
>
> NPM
>
> npm install --save react-native-mercadopago-checkout

**Linkeado:**

> react-native link react-native-mercadopago-checkout

Y estas listo para android, pero para ios te queda unos pasos mas que es bajar e instalar el sdk de [`mercado pago`](https://github.com/mercadopago/px-ios)

Para mas informacion entra al link de github que ahi esta detallado los pasos de todo lo que tenes que hacer, espero que te sirva!

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta.

Comment: @gbianchi ahi esta, agrege un poco mas de info, la verdad no se que mas poner si todo esta el readme de github

Comment: pues la respuesta tiene que ser una respuesta. vos solo estas indicando un link a un repo, esto valdria mas como comentario, ya que si el repo desaparece tu respuesta carece de sentido

Comment: gracias @LcsGrz esta respuesta me sirvio de mucho, si sirve la respuesta, es valido como tal

Answer (score 1):

Para integrarte contra el SDK de la V4 de MercadoPago en React Native no hay forma posible a menos que desarrolles un Bridge, ellos actualmente no dan soporte para React Native.

Hace poco, desarrolle el Bridge para la V4 de MercadoPago y lo estamos manteniendo up-to-date.

Podes ingresar a este repositorio para verlo:

- https://github.com/BlackBoxVision/react-native-mercadopago-px

El setup es relativamente sencillo, el único tema es que soportamos desde React Native >= 0.60

Espero sirva!